# How to close the app log output

Tags: logging, ibm-mobilefirst

When the app run based on MFPF, the log will be writen into the log file on device, the log information includes everything the user operation and app run, such as adapter called request/response, it contains much confidential business data. How to disabled the log output?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about client side log capture [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_client-side_log_capture.html?lang=en)

When in a development environment your logger is going to be set to DEBUG by default. You can change this using the [Logger API](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Logger.html?cp=SSHS8R_7.1.0%2F10-0-0-1-19&lang=en).

hybrid example setting client side:

```
WL.Logger.config({level:'trace'})
```

There is also a way that you can set client logger using the server. This is called client configuration profiles. Client configuration profiles sets a logging profile on the server for the client to use. The server profile will overwrite any Logger instances that you set using client side code.

To use this feature go to your MobileFirst Dashboard, click 'profiles' under the project, then set up a profile with the logging preference of your choice. Then in a convenient location that will not issue too many server hits, put the line of code:

```
WL.Logger.updateConfigFromServer();
```

You can read more about remote log collection [here](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-client-side-development/remote-controlled-client-side-log-collection/)

Also, make sure you are on the latest fix pack of whatever MobileFirst version you are on. There have been some fix packs released for Logger in the past month.

Comment: Chevy, Thanks. I have set level to 'FATAL', but it does not works! WL.Logger.config({ "enabled": false, "level": 'fatal', "capture":false});